# Sorting data with uneven rows and different indexes using R

Tags: r

I have 4 groups of population data each group have been typed for various markers and some markers are common to all groups, some are unique to each group, some markers are absence, and some markers may be observed in just certain groups for example only 2 of the 4 groups carry a particular marker. How do I sort 4 groups of data to generate one large table showing frequencies of all markers for each population. For example:

```
  Group1          Group2          Group3          Group4

  SNP   Fq        SNP  Fq         SNP   Fq        SNP  Fq
  11G1 0.00136    11G1 0.00122    20X3  0.00100   11G1 0.00120
  15T1 0.00136    15T9 0.00150    11A4  0.00150   15T1 0.00120
  15Y9 0.00136    15Y8 0.00200    12R1  0.00210   15Y9 0.00120
  15P7 0.00270    1597 0.00290    12R2  0.00260   15P7 0.00150
  15G1 0.00270    19U7 0.00300    12R3  0.00300   19U7 0.00250
  15Q7 0.00408    19P4 0.00350    13D4  0.00330   19P4 0.00350
  15U8 0.00410    20X3 0.00400    22W1  0.00341   22Y7 0.00550
  16E9 0.00680    22T2 0.00410    16E9  0.00540
  16T4 0.00700    22Y7 0.00600
                  22Y8 0.00660
```

I would like to generate an output file like this:

```
        Group1     Group2     Group3    Group4
  SNP   Fq         Fq         Fq         Fq
  11A4  0          0          0.00150    0
  11G1  0.00136    0.00122    0          0.00120
  12R1  0          0          0.00210    0
  12R2  0          0          0.00260    0
  12R3  0          0          0.00300    0
  13D4  0          0          0.00330    0
  15T1  0.00136    0          0          0.00120
  15T9  0          0.00150    0          0
  15Y8  0          0.00200    0          0
  15Y9  0.00136    0          0          0.00120
  15P57 0          0.00290    0          0
  15P7 0.00270     0          0          0.00150
  15G1 0.00270     0          0          0.00250
  15Q7 0.00408     0          0          0
  15U8 0.00410     0          0          0
  16E9 0.00680     0          0.00540    0
  16T4 0.00700     0          0          0
  19U7 0           0.00300    0          0
  19P4 0           0.00350    0          0.00350
  20X3 0           0.00400    0          0
  22T2 0           0.00410    0          0   
  22Y7 0           0.00600    0          0.00550
  22W1 0           0          0.00341    0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xtabs` to do this:

```
alldat <- do.call(rbind, list(Group1, Group2, Group3, Group4))
as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(Fq ~ SNP + Group, alldat))
```

## data:

```
Group1 <- read.table(text="Group SNP   Fq    
1 11G1 0.00136
1 15T1 0.00136
1 15Y9 0.00136
1 15P7 0.00270
1 15G1 0.00270
1 15Q7 0.00408
1 15U8 0.00410
1 16E9 0.00680
1 16T4 0.00700", header=TRUE)

Group2 <- read.table(text="Group SNP  Fq     
2 11G1 0.00122
2 15T9 0.00150
2 15Y8 0.00200
2 1597 0.00290
2 19U7 0.00300
2 19P4 0.00350
2 20X3 0.00400
2 22T2 0.00410
2 22Y7 0.00600
2 22Y8 0.00660", header=TRUE)

Group3 <- read.table(text="Group SNP   Fq     
3 20X3  0.00100
3 11A4  0.00150
3 12R1  0.00210
3 12R2  0.00260
3 12R3  0.00300
3 13D4  0.00330
3 22W1  0.00341
3 16E9  0.00540", header=TRUE)

Group4 <- read.table(text="Group SNP  Fq
4 11G1 0.00120
4 15T1 0.00120
4 15Y9 0.00120
4 15P7 0.00150
4 19U7 0.00250
4 19P4 0.00350
4 22Y7 0.00550", header=TRUE)
```